# Dynamically set the config map name and values to read in helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to helm charts. So please correct me if I am going wrong in understanding. I have a service which I am trying to deploy using helm charts. I want to change the config map name and its key values to read depending on deployment environment. Hence I want to add conditional logic in values.yaml.

Can someone point me to some document/link which explains how to add conditional logic in values.yaml?

Comment: Check this readme about [control structures](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures.md)

Comment: ( You cannot apply these structures in the `values.yaml` though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chart's `values.yaml` is primarily used to set default values, regardless of the environment. It exists to fill chart templates with values. It is not designed to be a template itself, so there is no logic you can apply inside a `values.yaml` file.

Each environment should have its own `values.yaml` file. You could store those inside the chart itself, like:

```
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── README
├── templates
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── deployment.app.yaml
│   └── service.app.yaml
├── values.prod.yaml
├── values.test.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Now, when you deploy a chart, you can use the environment specific `values.<env>.yaml` to override the default values. For your test environment this may look like this:

```
helm upgrade --install my-chart path/to/my/chart --values path/to/my/chart/values.test.yaml
```

Of course you could store the `values.<env>.yaml` files also outside of your chart directory. You just need to find a way to make them available at chart upgrade/install time to override the chart templates default `values.yaml`.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing it would be to pass one value in with helm install like:

```
--set environment=<value>
```

And then have multiple set of values in your values file for different environments like:

```
environment: <default>
env1:
  prop1: <value1>
  prop2: <value2>
env2:
  prop1: <value1>
  prop2: <value2>
```

Now in your configMap file make use of it like:

```
{{- if eq .Values.environment "env1" }}
  somekey: {{ .Values.env1.prop1 }}
{{- else }}
  somekey: {{ .Values.env2.prop1 }}
{{- end }}
```

That should do the trick for setting dynamic values according to environment or any such condition.

Apart from that there is one more thing I would like to bring to your notice that helm has few more inbuilt object just like `.Values`, one of which is `.Capabilities` so may be you can make use of `.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Platform` to find OS of the system